# str_replace() doesn't remove whitespace

Tags: php

I'm scraping some items from a website but there's a problem.

There is a website where the scraped price has a whitespace between the valuta symbol and the first number. But because of that whitespace, my price won't be added to the cart total when the items are added to the shoppingcart...

I've already tried preg_replace()

So I know I should use str_replace to remove the whitespaces but it just won't change.. Am I doing something wrong? My code:

```
$decprs = json_encode($articles[$i]->prijs);

        //$decodeprijs = "€ 9.99"
        $decodeprijs = json_decode($decprs);
        
        $nospace = (string) str_replace(' ', '', $decodeprijs);
        $nocomma = str_replace(',', '.', $nospace);
        $nohyphen = str_replace('-', '0', $nocomma);

        $officialprijs = $nohyphen;
        dd($officialprijs);

        dd -> "€ 9.99"
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Maybe the space is some special space, and not the usual one you can type on your keyboard?

Comment: I tried every solution I could find on stackoverflow. Any idea how I could analyze that 'special space'?

Comment: I've tried an online website that removes whitespaces and that one does the job, but I can't seem to find the method...

Comment: Since you only expect a few characters in the string, what if you used preg_filter or something that explicitly wants acceptable characters, not unacceptable characters to remove?

Comment: That is a good approach, but I find a solution to make it work

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
$nospace = preg_replace("/[\pZ\pC]+/u", "", $nohyphen);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be to extract the decimal number / currency symbol:

```
$decodeprijs = "€ 9.99";
//decimal number matches
preg_match_all('!\d+\.*\d*!', $decodeprijs, $decimal_matches);
preg_match_all('/€/', $decodeprijs, $euro_sign_matches);

print_r ($decimal_matches);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9.99
        )

) */
print_r ($euro_sign_matches);
/*
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => €
        )

)
 */
```